# Is there an alternative to sed that supports unicode?

Tags: sed, unicode, hexdump

For example:

```
sed 's/\u0091//g' file1
```

Right now, I have to do `hexdump` to get hex number and put into `sed` as follows:

```
$ echo -ne '\u9991' | hexdump -C
00000000  e9 a6 91                                          |...|
00000003
```

And then:

```
$ sed 's/\xe9\xa6\x91//g' file1
```

Answer (score 35):

Just use that syntax:

```
sed 's/馑//g' file1
```

Or in the escaped form:

```
sed "s/$(echo -ne '\u9991')//g" file1
```

(Note that older versions of Bash and some shells do not understand `echo -e '\u9991'`, so check first.)

Comment: Does sed count 馑 as one character or 3? That is, does `echo 馑 | sed s/...//` print anything?

Comment: @immibis Since `sed` has the g modifier it replaces all occurence also when they follow each other. Also sed should count it as one character, see: `echo -ne "馑" | wc -m` gives `1`. If you count the bytes (`wc -c`) it would return `3`. Did I understand your question correctly?

Comment: I meant: does `.` mean "one character" or "one byte"?

Comment: @immibis I matches one character hence `echo 馑 | sed s/...//` gives me `馑` (nothing is replaced)

Comment: @chaos: I'm not getting the character back. Maybe the behaviour depends on locale?

Comment: @choroba You need UTF-8 encoding to have all Chinese characters displayed correctly. What says your `locale`?

Comment: @chaos: It works under `en_US.UTF-8`, but doesn't under `C`.

Comment: @user253751 if you're worried about characters counts, try Raku (formerly known as Perl_6):  `echo '馑' | raku -ne '.chars.say;'` returns `1`. See: https://docs.raku.org/language/unicode

Answer (score 17):

Perl can do that:

```
echo 汉典“馑”字的基本解释 | perl -CS -pe 's/\N{U+9991}/Jin/g'
```

`-CS` turns on UTF-8 for standard input, output and error.

Comment: Perl can do almost anything.....

Comment: @wobbily_col Maybe. But it's written in C. So..if Perl can do almost anything C as the foundation of Perl can do anything. As it should be.

Comment: @wobbily_col In Raku (aka Perl6): `echo 汉典“馑”字的基本解释 | raku -pe 's:g/\x9991/Jin/'` #OUTPUT `汉典“Jin”字的基本解释`.

Answer (score 7):

**A number of versions of `sed` support Unicode**:

- [Heirloom sed](https://heirloom.sourceforge.net/tools.html), which is based on "original Unix material".
- [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), which is its own codebase.
- [Plan 9 sed](https://github.com/9fans/plan9port), which has been ported to Unix-like operating systems.

I couldn't find information on BSD sed, which I thought was strange, but I think the odds are good that it supports Unicode too. Unfortunately, there is no standard way to tell `sed` which encoding to use, so each one does this in its own ways.

Comment: Do they support UTF-16 with and without BOM ?

Comment: UTF-16 is pretty unusable in Unix-based OSes. It's also an abomination that should have never seen the light of day.

Comment: Whether or not they support UTF-16 depends on the implementation, and I'm afraid I don't have that data. I doubt that Plan 9 sed does (the original OS is UTF-8 everywhere), but I can't be sure, and even if it doesn't, the others might.

Answer (score 7):

With recent versions of BASH, just omit the quotes around the sed expression and you can use BASH's escaped strings. Spaces within the sed expression or parts of the sed expression that might be interpreted by BASH as wildcards can be individually quoted.

```
$ echo "饥馑荐臻" | sed s/$'\u9991'//g
饥荐臻
```

Comment: This should be the new accepted answer, simple and clean!

Comment: @AllenWang For reference, the `$'...'` type of quotes comes from ksh93 in 1993 while the `\uxxxx` within them comes from zsh in 2003 (inspired from GNU `printf`). Added in bash in 4.2 in 2010. So unless you're on macos which still comes with 3.2, that answer would have also been valid in 2015 when that question was asked.

Answer (score 6):

This works for me:

```
$ vim -nEs +'%s/\%u9991//g' +wq file1
```

It’s a drop more verbose than I’d like; here’s a full explanation:

- `-n` disable vim swap file
- `-E` Ex improved mode
- `-s` silent mode
- `+'%s/\%u9991//g'` execute the substitution command
- `+wq` save and exit

Comment: I suppose this modifies `file1` *in-place*, is that correct?

Comment: @gerrit that’s correct, and thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me with GNU sed (version 4.2.1):

```
$ echo -ne $'\u9991' | sed 's/\xe9\xa6\x91//g' | hexdump -C
$ echo -ne $'\u9991' | hexdump -C
00000000  e9 a6 91
```

(As another replacement for `sed` you could also use GNU `awk`; but it don't seem necessary.)

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
~$ echo 汉典“馑”字的基本解释 | raku -pe 's:g/\x9991/Jin/;'
汉典“Jin”字的基本解释
~$ echo "饥馑荐臻" | raku -pe s:g/'\x9991'//;
饥荐臻

~$ raku -e 'print "e", "e\x301", "\x000e9";'
eéé
~$ raku -e 'say "e\x301" eq "\x000e9";'
True
~$ echo "Stephane" | raku -pe 's/e/e\x301/;'
Stéphane
~$ echo "Stephane" | raku -pe 's/e/\x000e9/;'
Stéphane
```

[Rakudo 2020.10; code tested on GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14]

https://raku.org/